# PyTest how to properly mock imported ContextManager class and its function?

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, pytest, contextmanager

This is my sample code:

```
from path.lib import DBInterface

class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.something = "something"

    def _my_method(self, some_key, new_setup):
        with DBInterface(self.something) as ic:
            current_setup = ic.get(some_key)

        if current_setup != new_setup:
            with DBInterface(self.something) as ic:
                ic.set(new_setup)

    def public_method(self, some_key, new_setup):
        return self._my_method(some_key, new_setup)
```

(my actual code is bit more complex, but i cant put it here on public :)

Now, what I want to do is, I want to completely mock the imported class `DBInterface`, because I do not want my unittests to do anything in DB.
BUT I also need the `ic.get(some_key)` to return some value, or to be more precise, I need to set the value it returns, because thats the point of my unittests, to test if the method behave properly according to value returned from DB.

This is how far I got:

```
class TestMyClass:

    def test_extractor_register(self, mocker):
        fake_db = mocker.patch.object('my_path.my_lib.DBInterface')
        fake_db.get.return_value = None
        # spy_obj = mocker.spy(MyClass, "_my_method")
        test_class = MyClass()

        # Test new registration in _extractor_register
        result = test_class.public_method(Tconf.test_key, Tconf.test_key_setup)
        fake_db.assert_has_calls([call().__enter__().get(Tconf.test_key),
                                  call().__enter__().set(Tconf.test_key, Tconf.test_key_setup)])
        # spy_obj.assert_called_with(ANY, Tconf.test_key, Tconf.test_key_setup)
        assert result.result_status.status_code == Tconf.status_ok.status_code
        assert result.result_data == MyMethodResult.new_reg
```

But i am unable to set return value for `call().__enter__().get(Tconf.test_key)`.

I have been trying many approaches:

```
fake_db.get.return_value = None
fake_db.__enter__().get.return_value = None
fake_db.__enter__.get = Mock(return_value=None)
mocker.patch.object(MyClass.DBInterface, "get").return_value = None
```

None of that is actually working and I am running out of options I can think about.

Answer (score 0):

Without having more code or errors that are being produced, it's tough to provide a conclusive answer.

However, if you truly only need to specify a return value for `set()` I would recommend using `MagicMock` by virtue of `patch` --

```
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch("<MyClassFile>.DBInterface", autospec=True)
def test_extractor_register(mock_db):
        mock_db.set.return_value = "some key"
        # Rest of test code
```